# how are objects interpreted by "if"

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following:

```
class Foo
  def inspect
    false
  end

  def ==(other)
    false == other
  end
end

foo = Foo.new  # => false
foo            # => false
foo == false   # => true
foo == true    # => false
```

However

```
if foo then 'hi' end
# => 'hi'
```

What I was expecting was

```
if false then 'hi' end
# => nil
```

I was expecting `foo` to evaluate as `false` but it's not. How is `if` evaluating `foo` and why is it not `false`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only two objects in Ruby are considered to be "falsy": `false` (of `FalseClass`) and `nil` (of `NilClass`). You can't make another object mimic one of these, because Ruby runtime checks for these two concrete instances.

In your example, you have an instance of the `Foo` class. It is not `false` or `nil`, so it is considered "truthy". There's no way to make it evaluate as falsy value.

Comment: And again, Sergio is the first to provide a great answer. Let me just add the [link to Avdi's famous article dealing with the same issue](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/05/30/null-objects-and-falsiness/). Though, I must say, I am against `nil` being falsey. I think thad `nil` in Ruby is a lame ersatz for a properly implemented null object pattern. But it's too late to correct today.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: You can fork ruby :)

Comment: Not now, I am too busy rewriting SBML in Ruby. I satisfy myself [with kibbitzing :-)](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8365)